# Misery Business and the Yousuck effect

Tags: discussion, comments

Well, it's been 4 months. And I am impressed.

I am also a bit disappointed.

Before you read this, take it with a pinch of salt. I'm kinda new, still. I'm still learning the ropes. But I've done a lot of browsing through old questions and new questions, and all the comments in between.

Why am I disappointed, you might ask? Well, I'm disappointed because of the (re)occurence of the yousuck effect. No, I'm not talking about the stern warnings to "read the faq" or the "please post your code". I'm talking about this question. And there are others, if anyone wants to add them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904388/change-initialize-value-of-date-time-picker#comment26153235_17904388

The first comment on the question was by Mitch Wheat: "It's that time of day again..."

Look, I might have got an easy welcome to Stack Overflow. I posted some dumb stuff. I also posted some good questions, if I say so myself.

But just because it's the time of day where the foreign people (not sure from where because they could be many nationalities) come onto the site and post so-so questions **DOES NOT** mean that you should treat them like crap.

I know that I wouldn't want to be treated like a useless statistic if I was a foreign person with a question.

And for all those other high-rep people out there, I know what you are like. I know that you are generous. I know that you help me out when I get stuck. But please, please just realize that every new account is, well, a new person. And that is an account that should be treated with utmost respect. And really, the high-rep people should be setting the good examples.

... not to pick on you, but Mitch, I guess that the comment was deleted for a good reason. I think that it was a good move to delete it.

---

So in conclusion, just realize that there are people who care. I hate this stuff. I did a "dodgy upvote" because I felt bad for the poor guy. So please, please just do the downvotes and the flags. Maybe you could try to help them out once in a while.

But try to keep the snarky comments to yourself.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like everyone has their bad days. Your edit is fine IMO.

Comment: Please don't make this a duplicate question. I already read the Could we please... question. Bottom line: I wouldn't have posted this if I thought the other question was enough.

Comment: The comment was totally inappropriate, and I totally appreciate your sentiment, but at 7,000 questions a day, closevoting and downvoting is the community's only way of self-defense. We do not want these types of questions because they actively harm the site by making it a place that eventually no expert will want to enter to answer stuff any more. The problem with the question wasn't that it was asked by a foreigner, but that it was trivial and could have been solved by 30 seconds of Googling. If you want to help, post a friendly comment guiding the OP to a more suitable place.

Comment: Aside from the comment, it's worth noting that respect has to be mutual. I see no sign of respect for the community's time in that original question - no sign of research, or reading through the numerous articles about how to ask a good question. Note that users have to go through an interstitial before asking their first question, and anyone who bothered to read that interstitial would know that this *wasn't* a good question. So while I agree that the comment was bad, so was the question - it was disrespectful of those people who might try to help.

Comment: Thanks. Your comments were very insightful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Snarky comments used to be a far worse problem on the site than they are now.

But you're right, the comment was inappropriate.  That's why we have comment flags, and that's why we delete such comments on a regular basis.  Worth noting: Mitch thought better of his comment, and retracted it himself an hour later.  I've done the same myself.

Did you have any other questions?

Comment: A couple. But they are unrelated, and I'll post them when I get around to it.

Comment: Um, thanks for the random upvote...?