# Is it okay to use comment flags for "this person is being sort of a jerk"?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I was thinking about [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190810/misery-business-and-the-yousuck-effect), and [this linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently).

Is it okay to use comment flags for comments which are not outright offensive, but in which the person is still being somewhat of a jerk? Things like, "Your code is terrible, you need to change it." or "Your application is totally pointless." or "If you turn back now, we'll grant you a quick death!"

In other words, comments which are unfriendly, would be read negatively, and which aren't constructive, but also don't outright qualify as "offensive." Do these count as flag-worthy?

I don't have any actual examples off the top of my head, but I'm hoping this is clear enough. If it's not, let me know, and I can think of some better ones.

Comment: You know, there is a "not constructive" comment flag reason. "In other words, comments which are unfriendly, would be read negatively, and which **aren't constructive**, but also don't outright qualify as "offensive."" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Doorknob That's a fair answer. Me no think straight this late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the "offensive" comment flag is labeled "rude or offensive". If it's not offensive, but rude, you can use that.

Note that all comment flags are the same; there is no special "offensive" comment flag, unlike with post flags. That said, **do not** use the "offensive" post flag if it's not the post but the comments underneath it that are offensive. And speaking of post flags, if there are too many  comments to flag you can raise a custom flag on either the post or one of the comments to tell us what is going on.